# algorithm to select a pair of vectors for the best "zigzag" profile

Tags: algorithm, vector, polar-coordinates

I have a set of distinct 2D vectors (over real numbers), pointing in different directions. We are allowed to pick a pair of vectors and construct their linear combination, such that the coefficients are positive and their sum is 1.
In simple words we are allowed to take a "weighted average" of any two vectors.

My goal is for an arbitrary direction to pick a pair of vectors whose "weighted average" is in this direction and is maximized.
Speaking algebraically given vectors **a** and **b** and a direction vector **n** we are interested in maximizing this value:

[ **a** cross **b** ] / [ (**a** - **b**) cross **n** ]

i.e. pick **a** and **b** which maximize this value.

To be concrete the application of this problem is for sailing boats. For every apparent wind direction the boat will have a velocity given by a polar diagram. Here's an example of such a diagram: [image: Velocity diagram]

(Each line in this diagram corresponds to a specific wind magnitude). Note the "impossible" front sector of about 30 degrees in each direction.

So that in some direction the velocity will be high, for some - low, and for some directions it's impossible to sail directly (for instance in the direction strictly opposite to the wind).

If we need to advance in a direction in which we can't sail directly (or the velocity isn't optimal) - it's possible to advance in zigzags. This is called tacking.

Now, my goal is to recalculate a new diagram which denotes the average advance velocity in any direction, either directly or indirectly. For instance for the above diagram the corrected diagram would be this:

[image: Corrected velocity diagram]

Note that there are no more "impossible" directions. For some directions the diagram resembles the original one, where it's best to advance directly, and no maneuver is required. For others - it shows the maximum average advance velocity in this direction assuming the most optimal maneuver is periodically performed.

What would be the most optimal algorithm to calculate this? Assume the diagram is given as a discrete set of azimuth-velocity pairs, from which we can calculate the vectors.

So far I just check all the vector pairs to select the best. Well, there're cut-off criterias, such as picking only vectors with positive projection on the advance direction, and opposite perpendicular projections, but still the complexity is O(N^2).
I wonder if there's a more efficient algorithm.

**EDIT**

Many thanks to @mcdowella. For both computer-science and sailor answers!

I too thought in terms of convex polygon, figured out that it's only worth probing vectors on that hull (i.e. if you take a superposition of 2 vectors on this hull, and try to replace one of them by a vector which isn't on this hull, the result would be worse since new vector's projection on the needed direction is worse than of both source vectors).

However I didn't realize that any "weighted average" of 2 vectors is actually a straight line segment connecting those vectors, hence the final diagram is indeed this convex hull! And, as we can see, this is also in agreement with what I calculated by "brute-force" algorithm.

Comment: I am afraid that the reality is much worse than O(n^2). Sometimes (when going downwind) it is beneficial to make more than one jibe.

Comment: @user58697: I think it doesn't really matter how many jibes you perform, as long as the conditions are constant they probably follow the same pattern.

Comment: The pattern I have in mind is a broad reach follow by a run followed by jibed broad reach. It could be better than just two broad reaches. Yet it requires two point changes. O(n^3) at best. In general, a brachistochrone problem is highly non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the computer science answer

A tacking strategy gives you the convex combination of the vectors from the legs that make up the tacks.

So consider the outline made by just one contour in your diagram. The set of all possible best speeds and directions is the convex polygon formed by taking all convex combinations of the vectors to the contour. So what you want to do is form the convex hull of your contour (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). To find out how to go fast in any particular direction, intersect that vector with the convex hull, and use tacks with legs that correspond to the corners on either side of the edge of the convex hull that you intersect with.

Looking at your diagram, the contour is concave straight upwind and straight downwind, which is what you would expect. However there is also another concave section, somewhere between 4 and 5 O'Clock and also symmetrically between 7 and 8 O'Clock, which appears as a straight line in your corrected diagram - so I guess there is a third direction to tack in, using two reaches on the same side of the wind which I don't recognise from traditional sailing.

Comment: You are the man! Thanks a lot! I'll have to agree with you, and it's a shame I didn't figure this out by myself.

Comment: Since you are both a sailor and a programmer, may I ask you to try an application we're developing? It's a sailor assist app with weather routing, land/obstacle avoiding and many customization options. http://cruiseaider.com/ (available as online demo and android app)

Comment: Thanks - I find that I can easily create a route from Strangford to Whiterock in your online app that looks plausible - although I'm not competent to tell whether it is really sensible or not. You don't mention tides. Do you take them into account? Here I have chosen an area (Strangford narrows) with tides of up to 8 knots.

Comment: Thanks for trying this. Theoretically the routing algorithm is capable to account for anything: wind, current (oceanic and tidal streams), as well as your preferences such as preferred proximity to coast, storm avoidance and etc.
However in this online demo there is no tidal data, we use only the free wind/current forecast given by NOAA, and the chart is very basic. Android app allows to use somewhat more detailed charts provided by OSM.

Comment: We are currently developing a next generation of this, with much improved algorithm (in terms of precision / calculation complexity), options to load custom charts and forecast, and an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

First the ex-laser sailor answer

At least for going straight upwind or downwind, the obvious guess is to tack so that each leg is of the same length and of the same bearing to the wind. If the polar diagram is symmetric around the upwind-downwind axis this is correct. Suppose upwind is the Y axis and possible legs are (A, B), (-A, B), (a, b) and (-a, b). Symmetrical tacking moves (A, B)/2 + (-A, B)/2 = (0, B) and the other symmetrical tack gives you (0, b). Asymmetrical tacking is (-A, B)a/(a+A) + (a, b)A/(a+A) = (0, (a/(a+A))B + (A/(a+A))b) and if b!=B lies between b and B and so is not as good as whichever of b or B is best.

For any direction which lies between the port and starboard tacks that you would take to work your way upwind, the obvious strategy is to change the length of those legs but not their direction so that the average vector traveled is in the required direction. Is this the best strategy? If not, the better strategy is making progress upwind faster that the port and starboard tacks that you would take to work your way upwind, which I think is a contradiction - so for any direction which lies between the port and starboard tacks made to go upwind I think the best strategy is indeed to make those tacks but alter the leg lengths to go in the required direction. The same thing should apply for tacking downwind, if you have a boat that makes that a good idea.

Comment: A true sailor answer! I was about to say the same, but I couldn't parse my own answer either.

Comment: Thanks, it's a really interesting point. For going strictly upwind and downwind with symmetric diagram the strategy is obvious, however in other directions - it's a really good point. Note the "flat-tire" profile of the corrected diagram for upwind and downwind regions (where tacking is beneficial) - it actually suggests what you say! Speaking strictly I believe it's not precisely correct, but as a first-guess it sounds reasonable. Perhaps an optimized algorithm would try combinations in the proximity of those master directions